# Diablo III's tooltip script for Gaming Stack Exchange

Tags: script

Blizzard has [a userscript for displaying tooltips when linking to game element descriptions on their webpage](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/tooltip/). This user script adds this functionality to Gaming Stack Exchange by incorporating this script when browsing the site.

For instance, here's a screenshot from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-are-the-details-behind-fists-of-thunders-faster-spirit-generation):

> [image: screenshot showing a tooltip appears when hovering over a link to the skill description]

**License and Info**

Public domain, version 1.0.

**Installation**

**[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/132789.user.js) | [Source Code](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/132789)**

**Credits**

Shamelessly copied from (the also public-domain) http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/132780.